# How does Socketio in real-time chat app work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, sockets, socket.io

I have the following backend and frontend codes. When I try to exchange a private message between only two users,and I tried one of the following and  I am getting different outcomes which made me confused and how socketio genrally works? So, what are differences amongst:

**1. socket.to(data.sent_to).emit("new-message-received",data)**

**2. socket.emit("new-message-received",data)**

**3. socketIO.to(data.sent_to).emit("new-message-received",data)**
in the backend code?

also

**1. what is the difference amongst the socket in the frontend and the socket in the backend code?**

**2. what is the difference between socketIO of the backend and io on the frontend code?**

```
import http from "http"
import {Server} from "socket.io"
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const socketIO = new Server(server)
socketIO.on("connection", (socket) => {
const clientId = socket.handshake.query.id
socket.join(clientId)
socket.on("send-new-message",(data)=>{
socketIO.to(data.sent_to).emit("new-message-received",data) //for the receiver
socket.emit("new-message-received",data) //for the sender
  })
```

frontend code

```
const socket = io.connect("http://10.0.2.2:4000",{ query: { id: currentUser?._id }}
socket.emit("send-new-message",data)
socket.on("new-message-received", dataObj => {setRooms(prevRooms =>[...dataObj,prevRooms]) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd share my opinion aboutb your issue: Socket.IO is a library that enables real-time, bidirectional communication between a client (usually a web browser) and a server. It establishes a persistent connection between the client and server, allowing real-time data exchange through events.

- To exchange private messages between two users using Socket.IO, you can follow a couple of different approaches:

+**Room-based Approac**h:

Each user joins a unique room using socket.join(room), where the room represents the private messaging channel between the two users.
User A sends a private message by emitting an event to the specific room using io.to(room).emit(event, data).
User B, who has also joined the same room, receives the private message.

```js
// User A
socket.join('private-room');
socket.to('private-room').emit('private-message', 'Hello User B');

// User B
socket.join('private-room');
socket.on('private-message', (message) => {
  console.log('Received private message:', message);
});
```

**User-based Approach**:

+Each user has a unique identifier (e.g., user ID or username) stored on the server.
User A sends a private message by emitting an event directly to User B's socket ID using io.to(socketId).emit(event, data).
User B receives the private message using a listener on their socket.

```js
// User A
const userBSocketId = getUserBSocketIdFromStorage(); // Retrieve User B's socket ID from storage or database
io.to(userBSocketId).emit('private-message', 'Hello User B');

// User B
socket.on('private-message', (message) => {
  console.log('Received private message:', message);
});
```

And Here Is Config Server Side By NodeJS:

```js
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Data structure to store user and socket mappings
const userSocketMap = new Map();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // Store the user ID and socket ID
  socket.on('store-user', (userId) => {
    userSocketMap.set(userId, socket.id);
  });

  // Handle private channel request
  socket.on('private-channel-request', (data) => {
    const { senderId, recipientId } = data;

    // Get the socket IDs of the sender and recipient
    const senderSocketId = userSocketMap.get(senderId);
    const recipientSocketId = userSocketMap.get(recipientId);

    // Emit private channel established event to the sender and recipient
    io.to(senderSocketId).to(recipientSocketId).emit('private-channel-established', {
      channelId: 'unique-channel-id',
      participants: [senderId, recipientId],
    });
  });

  // Handle private messages
  socket.on('private-message', (data) => {
    const { channelId, senderId, recipientId, message } = data;

    // Get the socket ID of the recipient
    const recipientSocketId = userSocketMap.get(recipientId);

    // Emit the private message event to the recipient
    io.to(recipientSocketId).emit('private-message-received', {
      channelId,
      senderId,
      message,
    });
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Socket.IO server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the questions

Comment: but i am not asking on how to do them rather how each method is different?